# Unity Ads 2.0 Eclipse Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unityads

I am trying to get UnityAds 2.0 Library in one of my eclipse Project. I have imported Project from here https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-ads-android. I have solved other errors in project but I am still getting two errors in my project called below.

```
VERSION_CODE cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

and

```
The import android.webkit.WebResourceError cannot be resolved
```

My Target SDK is Google API 22

Let me know what I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on target SDK version 23 or better.

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-ads-android/blob/master/lib/build.gradle#L14